# Does JTable have a built-in function to sort a column in descending/ascending order?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I have a JTable that's connected to a database through JDBC (h2 database) and it displays data properly. I was wondering if there's a function in Swing that lets you easily sort the data based on the column's values, perhaps on the click of the column header. If not, how should one go about implementing a sorting function? I was thinking perhaps querying the database and storing the read data somewhere and then sorting it based on their values then creating a new JTable to display the newly sorted data but that seems kind like a hassle and I'm pretty sure there's a much simpler way to do it that I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check JTable's [setAutoCreateRowSorter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter(boolean)) method :

```
yourTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

This should allow sorting by clicking on a column